# Change braces in vuejs to something else

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to change braces `{{ msg }}` in vuejs to something else, for example: `{( msg )}`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can change the delimiters like so:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['{(', ')}']
})
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters